# Proving Property of Dirac Delta

Tags: calculus, dirac-delta

I need to prove the idendity of $$\delta(g(x)) = \Sigma \frac{\delta(x-x_i)} {|g'(x_i)|}$$ and we know that $$g(x_i) = 0$$

So I think we can write,

$$g(x) = (x - x_1)(x-x_2)...(x-x_i)$$

so we are actually trying to find,

$$\delta((x - x_1)(x-x_2)...(x-x_i))$$

Now I am not sure what to do. I tried to write $g(x)$ in terms of $g'(x)$ to catch some sort of similarity but it did not work out well.

**In another approach**, I tried to make a taylor expansion around $x_i$ which gives something like

$$g(x = x_i) = g(x_i) + (x - x_i)g'(x_i) + ...$$

(In here I ignored the higer terms with no reason actually)

Hence around $x_i$, $\delta(g(x)) =  \frac{\delta(x-x_i)} {|g'(x_i)|}$ (by using $\delta(g'(x_i) (x-x_i)) = \frac{\delta(x-x_i)} {|g'(x_i)|}$)

since we have $i$ points,

$$\delta(g(x)) = \Sigma \frac{\delta(x-x_i)} {|g'(x_i)|}$$

Is this looks stupid ?

Comment: Yes. That $g$ is smooth with only finitely many zeros $x_i$ where $g'(x_i)\ne 0$ means $g(x) = (x - x_1)(x-x_2)...(x-x_i) h(x)$ with $h$ smooth non-vanishing and $h'(x_i) = \frac{g'(x_i)}{\prod_{j \ne i} (x_i-x_j)}$. Then you didn't define $\delta(g(x))$ so there is quite nothing to prove.

Comment: @reuns I did not understand much. Hmm are you meaning that I forget h(x) so I am doing things wrong ?

Comment: Sure, once we know the sign of $g(x_1-1)$ only the sign of the $g'(x_i)$ are constrained but $|g'(x_i)|$ can be anything.

Comment: I still cant do it

Comment: I meant $h(x_i) = \frac{g'(x_i)}{\prod_{j \ne i} (x_i-x_j)}$ above. Do what ?

Comment: @reuns I mean I did not understand how this infor would help me

Comment: Would help for what ? You didn't define $\delta(f(x))$ for any kind of function $f$. If you define it as $<\delta(f(x)),\phi>=\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{n}{2} 1_{|f(x)|<1/n} \phi(x)dx$ then $\delta(g(x)) = \Sigma \frac{\delta(x-x_i)} {|g'(x_i)|}$ is a theorem.